# How to create an Installer in VIsual Studio, C#

Tags: installation

I am a Local Freelancer
I develop Software in C# 2.0 and SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.
I used Crystal Reports for Reporting 11 .

So, When I went to Client Machine,
There I need to install all the above mentioned software.

Please suggest me!

1. Which Programming Languages give me Platform independent easy to install softwares, without any pre-requisites.
2. Can I build a installer for C# that is easy to install in all windows operating system.
   32 bit machine requires sql32
   64 bit requires sql64

its pretty difficult to create the installer.

Please help me.
Can I use C# or I need to change my platform?
I need to create a Easy installer for the user for all windows operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

The Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a toolset that builds Windows installation packages from XML source code. The toolset supports a command line environment that developers may integrate into their build processes to build MSI and MSM setup packages.